# Performance tuning VBA code in large procedure

Tags: performance, debugging, vba

I've been asked to tune the performance of a specific function which loads every time a worksheet is opened (so it's important that it doesn't make things slow). One of the things that seems to make this function slow is that it does a long call to the database (which is remote), but there are a bunch of other possibilities too. So far, I've been stepping through the code, and when something seems to take a long time making a note of it as a candidate for tuning.

I'd like a more objective way to tell which calls are slowing me down. Searching for timing and VBA yields a lot of results which basically amount to "Write a counter, and start and stop it either side of the critical section" (often with the macro explicitly called). I was wondering whether there was a way to (in the debugger) do something like "Step to next line, **and tell me the time elapsed**".

If not, can someone suggest a reasonable macro that I could use in the Immediate window to get what I'm after? Specifically, I would like to be able to time an arbitrary line of code within a larger procedure (rather than a whole procedure at once, which is what I found through Google).

Comment: Or perhaps post the code so we could see if it is the issue? :)

Comment: Neither possible (legal dept) nor desirable (>1000 lines, with performance-sensitive bits littered throughout) I'm afraid, but the principle isn't based on one bit of code; it's "how can I do this in a generic way whenever I'm trying to judge the performance of a section."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keywords for your further search would be to look for a "Profiler" for VBA. I've heard of VB Watch and VBA Code Profiler System (VBACP) as well as from Stephen Bull's PerfMon, but sparing the latter they're mostly not free.

So far for the official part of my answer, and I toss in some extra in terms of maybe useless suggestions:
Identifying "slow" code by "humanly measurement" (run a line and say: "Woah, that takes forever") in the debugger  is certainly helpful, and you can then start looking into why they're slow. Your remote database call may take quite long if it has to transmit a lot of data - in which cases it may be a good idea to timestamp the data on both ends and ask the DB whether data had been modified before you grab it.
Writing the data into the sheet may be slow depending on the way you write it - which can sometimes be improved by writing arrays to a range instead of some form of iteration.
And I probably don't need to tell you about ScreenUpdating and EnableEvents and so on?

Comment: I agree with recommending Perfmon.

Comment: I will look into PerfMon. Sadly anything in the database pipeline outside of making client calls is off-limits.

Comment: Accepted; I was hoping for something a little quicker and dirtier than "use a profiler," but that'll have to do.